# Production Website Frozen at /wp-admin/upgrade.php

Tags: upgrade

My client upgraded the production Wordpress site to 3.5.2 without disabling the active plugins. He called when the site froze at upgrade.php.

I opened the database and updated the wp-options table to set db_upgraded to 0.

I renamed /wp-content/plugins to disable all plugins, enabled WP_ALLOW_REPAIRS and the repair page reported all OK. I closed the browser, reopened it, cleared the cache and went back to /wp-admin.

Without even asking for login information, the page redirects to /wp-admin/upgrade.php.

The frontend of the site remains functional.

I do not know what else to do. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Check that all files are ok. Are there any errors with debug enabled? This kind of thing is impossible to guess really.

Comment: no errors when debug is enabled

Comment: In these instances I resort to FTP. [Grab the latest version](http://wordpress.org/latest.zip), extract, leave to upload & overwrite.